# Is there anyone successfully simulate I2C by GPIO at userspace, and using the sysfs?

Tags: linux, i2c, gpio, sysfs

I want to use two gpio pins to simulate the I2C communication, the two gpio pins are already in the `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/gpio` directory, it works ok --- when I write to a pin, I can detect the volt change on it.

And I have already wrote the code which implement the I2C protocol, but it doesn't work well.

I am not using i2c-gpio, i2c-algo-bit, or something like i2c-dev module/driver, just by read/write the `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/gpio/mode` and `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/gpio/pin` directory, including controlling time sequence, but seems it not work.

Since I2C has a demand for time sequence, and Linux is not a real-time system --- especially from userspace. I wonder if this method is practicable.

If anyone had achieved that?

Comment: Are you trying to implement I2C master or slave? Master is easily implemented by bit-banging even on a system like Linux. Timing is not an issue. (It's a bit harder to do slave mode.) One thing: I2C lines **must** be set for open-collector/drain mode. Make sure you've set the GPIO pin mode correctly.

Comment: @DoxyLover Thanks for reply, I want to implement the master. Maybe I leave out the open-collector/drain mode, I will try it again, thanks!